# Is it possible to add in-app Billing without source code on apk?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm using an apk that already have google services installed on it.
I want to add in-app billing but i dont have source code to apk.
Is it possible to do it? The apk already have google services on it.

Comment: No. Without updating the app it's not possible

Comment: Are you seriously a developer?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Without source code implementation of in-app purchase is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In-app billing required coding so without source code how you will add codes and build updated app?